# FAERS Quarterly Extracts and openFDA

Tags: openfda, releasing-data

Does anyone know, on average, how long it takes for openFDA to be updated once the quarterly extracts are released? Is there a way to track this? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

openFDA refreshes its Drug Event endpoint once a week, which means a new quarterly FAERS release would get picked up within 7 days after the release.

You could track this, for example, by making periodic calls to https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json and checking `meta.results.total` value. It increases significantly with each FAERS release.

Comment: Thanks, Denis. You wouldn't happen to know when the data for Q3 2020 will be released? I have submitted an inquiry to CDER/SBIA; however, they have not gotten back to me yet. Thanks again.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't. Asking CDER directly is the right thing to do; hopefully they'll get back to you with an answer soon.